# How can I use LPSTARTUPINFO and LPPROCESSINFO properly in CreateProcessA?

Tags: c++, winapi

I tried to use the tutorials around about using the CreateProcessA wherein it uses the `STARTUPINFOA` and `LPPROCESS_INFORMATION`.

However, when I tried to use the LPSTARTUPINFOA and LPPROCESS_INFORMATION and sadly it didn't work.

```
//Working

STARTUPINFOA startUpInfo = {0};

PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = {0};

startUpInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOA);

CreateProcessA(NULL, "c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &startUpInfo, &processInformation);


//Fails


LPSTARTUPINFOA startUpInfo;

LPPROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;

startUpInfo = (LPSTARTUPINFOA)malloc(sizeof(startUpInfo));

processInformation = (LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)malloc(sizeof(processInformation));

ZeroMemory(startUpInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFOA));

ZeroMemory(processInformation, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

startUpInfo->cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOA);

CreateProcessA(NULL,"c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, startUpInfo, processInformation);
```

I expect that both would work successfully, however, I wonder why `LPSTARTUPINFOA` and `LPPROCESS_INFORMATION` fails. Is there anyone who can enlighten me about my error in this program below.

Comment: You're mallocing the wrong size. `sizeof(startUpInfo)` is the size of a _pointer_, not the size of the struct.  Use `sizeof(STARTUPINFOA)`, or better yet use `new STARTUPINFOA`.  (Same for `processInformation`).

Comment: If you would add error checking to your code, then the system would tell you what you did wrong. So many questions in the winapi tag can readily by answered by the asker if only error checking was performed.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I realize that I am using the startUpInfo which is a pointer and now it works.

Comment: Before you leave this topic, try and add error checking and see what it tells you. Hopefully that will help convince you of the importance and value of error checking.

Comment: I'd thought that it is just a boolean so I used the if statement, however, I realized that I should should GetLastError. Thank you for your time in answering my question. @DavidHeffernan

Comment: Yeah, you need to check the return value first to see if there was an error, and then call `GetLastError` if there was. Most win32 functions are like that, but not all. Have to check the doc for each one. Btw, the second argument to `CreateProcess` should point to a writeable buffer (a literal is not).  Your code gets away with it because of a quirk with the ANSI implementation, but you would not get away with it if you used `CreateProcessW`. And you should be using `CreateProcessW`.